# How can I link 2 django templates with one button?

Tags: django, templates, web, django-templates, django-views

I need to link to link two django templates with a button on my index page,what would be the best way of doing it? I need to link bis.html. This is how I have things set up.

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^$/bis', BisView.as_view()),
]
```

> views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
class BisView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'bis.html'
```

> index.html

```
...
<li><a href="/bis">Bisection</a></li>
...
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? (Apart from the broken regex, `$` goes at the end.)

Comment: Thank you, I always forget how to do it